# How to encode the time in an Markov Jump Process

Tags: markov-chain

Assume I have a time continuous Markov process with only a few (let's say 2, in reality a few more, like 5) states. I can measure these states in real data and I want to estimate the transfer probability matrices of the process. The states occur in random order and in random length. So for example state 1 hold on for 60 secs, then the system switches to state 2 and stays there for only 5 secs before returning to state 1 for 10 secs and so on.

My question is, how do I incorporate the time when calculating the TPMs? My idea is to introduce new substates, e.g. state1_short, state2_mid and so on. The problem will be to determine what short, long etc. shall be.

Is there another way, what are the keywords I could search for?

Thank you very much!

Comment: OP: Since you are still active on the site, I feel entitled to ask: did you get something from the answer below?

Answer (score 4):

A time continuous Markov process switches states after some exponentially distributed random times whose parameter depends on the state one is at. Thus, you should use the observations to estimate:

- the parameters $\lambda_x$ such that one leaves state $x$ after a random time $T_x$ such that, for every $t$, $P(T_x\geqslant t)=\mathrm e^{-\lambda_xt}$
- the probabilities $q_{xy}$ that, when one leaves state $x$, one jumps to state $y$, for each $y\ne x$

Then the transition rate of the jumps from $x$ to $y\ne x$ is $$r_{xy}=\lambda_xq_{xy}.$$
The MLE estimator of $\lambda_x$ based on the observation of $n_x$ sojourn times $t_k^x$ is such that $$\frac1{\hat\lambda_x}=\frac1{n_x}\sum_{k=1}^{n_x}t_k^x.$$ The MLE estimator of $q_{xy}$ based on the number $n_{xy}$ of times one leaves $x$ for $y$ is $$\hat q_{xy}=\frac{n_{xy}}{n_x}.$$ Thus, one often estimates $r_{xy}$ by $$\hat r_{xy}=\frac{n_{xy}}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_x}t_k^x}.$$