# Time dependent representation for time series events with different time gaps?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, recurrent-neural-network, unevenly-spaced-time-series, representative

In natural language processing, we can treat characters as evenly spaced time series in RNN models where time gaps are independent of the sequence and only sequential positions matter.

If I want to encode five sentences(as five events) with different timestamp gaps into five time steps using a RNN model how can I encode the time spans(or silences)? The durations of the sentences(events) do not matter.

I searched Google and found three related methods: [here for Markov Jump Process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/125252/103153) and [here for the duration of an event](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.00065.pdf) and [here for images](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/472331/103153), but what I want is how to represent the time gaps between events in neural networks(events or natural language).

I tried adding a special time token(represented as a vector) for every 10 seconds of silence(between every two sentences) and the performance seems acceptable, but are there any better or standard solutions?

Comment: There probably isn’t going to be a straightforward way of handling this if your model is in discrete time. If you don’t want to investigate continuous-time or point process models, I suggest you combine the values and time gaps (inter-event times) and feed that as data to the network: your new dataset is $\{(y_i, w_i)\}_{i=1}^n$, with $w_i = t_i - t_{i-1}$

Comment: @MaximilianAigner It seems unintuitive since the $w_i$ does not belong to $y_i$, $w_i$ is something between $y_i$ and $y_{i−1}$. Should it be attached to a sentence/event?

Comment: you can think of it like a renewal process, where the $w_i$ are iid draws from some distribution $F$ and the marks $y_i$ are modelled independently. If $F$ is the exponential cdf, you have a marked poisson process. Of course you can also add dependence between the $y_i$ and $w_i$.

Comment: See e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.09690.pdf